# cordova org.chromium.socket plugin Reference Error

Tags: javascript, sockets, cordova

I am developing a mobile app with Apache Cordova 3.5 and I am trying to use the org.chromium.socket plugin. 
Unfortunately, I always get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: chrome is not defined. (or org... depending on what I try)

For instance: When I want to call the function create(), I have tried using all the following options but non of them work.

- chrome.socket.create("tcp", null, Socket_create_callback)
- org.chromium.socket.Socket.create( "tcp", null, Socket_create_callback)
- chrome.chromium.socket.Socket.create( "tcp", null, Socket_create_callback)
- org.chromium.socket("tcp", null, Socket_create_callback)

I added the plugin using the line

- cordova plugin add org.chromium.socket

I can see the library (socket.js) from the chrome inspector, I suppose it is loaded automatically when it loads cordova.js. I am using Android 4.4 emulator.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna have to put your plugin usage code after the *deviceready* event has fired!

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
//your code here
//chrome.socket.create("tcp", null, Socket_create_callback)
}, false);
```

if your are using ionic or angularjs your could leverage some other tricks too.